# Create sub-list and remove values from previous list

Tags: java

I want to create a sub-list in Java and remove values that are in sub-list from the previous List. My program correctly creates sub-list, but than it doesn't remove the correct values from previous-list.

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     List<Object> sub = new ArrayList<Object>(prevoiusList.subList(0, 6));

     for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
         previousList.remove(j);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first `j=0` and you remove the first element. When doing so you shift all other elements, so the second element becomes first and so on.

On next iteration `j=1`, so you remove the second element, which was originally the third...

In order to fix this issue, use only `0` index, or an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in a single line

```
prevoiusList.subList(0,6).clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just do :

```
previousList = previousList.subList(7, previousList.size());
```

Comment: Check the [List#subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) docs, it returns a _view_ of the original list. Thus performing modifications on the sublist could end up in a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 1):

To "move" 6 elements from one list to create another list:

```
List<Object> list;
List<Object> subList = new ArrayList<Object>(list.subList(0, 6));
list.removeAll(subList);
```

It should be noted that [`List.subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29), returns a *view* of the list, so modifications to the origianl list will be reflected in the sub list, hence creating the new list and passing the sub list to the constructor.

To put this in a loop:

```
List<Object> list;
while (list.size() > 5) {
    List<Object> subList = new ArrayList<Object>(list.subList(0, 6));
    list.removeAll(subList);
    // do something with subList
}
// list now has 0-5 elements
```

Comment: If the same value appears multiple times in the original list, all instances of it will be removed by removeAll(). This could have unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a view of the original list, while removing the elements of the view from the original list:

```java
List<Object> sublistViewOfOrginal = original.subList(0, n);
original.subList(0, n).clear();
```

To use the view as a list (with access to the usual `List` API methods), construct a concrete `ArrayList` from the view:

```java
List<Object> actualListAsPortionOfOriginal = new ArrayList<>(sublistViewOfOrginal);
```