# Remove common entries from 2 Arraylist

Tags: java, collections

I want to remove common entries from 2 `ArrayList` :

```
A = [1,2,3,5]
B = [1,2,3,7]
```

O/P :

```
A = [5]
B = [7]
```

Is there any java8 function for above ? How to handle it efficiently ?

Comment: Please provide more information because very few details..  
Which is the relation of 2 arrays? Is one to one or?
Entries are on the same index or?

Comment: Use `retainAll` to get common element and use `removeAll` to remove them from each list https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943335/4207306, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16634482/4207306

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is efficient enough:

```
 public void removeCommonElements(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    List<Integer> list3 = list1.stream()
            .filter(list2::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list1.removeAll(list3);
    list2.removeAll(list3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> list3 = list1.stream()
        .filter(var -> {return !list2.contains(var);})
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> list4 = list2.stream()
            .filter(var -> {return !list1.contains(var);})
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can do this.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,5));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,7));

List<Integer> commonElements = new ArrayList<>(list1);
commonElements.retainAll(list2);
list1.removeAll(commonElements);
list2.removeAll(commonElements);

System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Prints

```
[5]
[7]
```